# Access Rules on project.project Odoo11

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-11

I have a new group (Project Lead). This group needs to read other projects, and write his own project. 
Example: user1 is a manager in project001 and user2 is a manager in project002. We need for user1: edit only project001 and he needs to read project002.

I have tried the code below, but it did not work.

In XML

```
<record id="group_project_lead" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Lead</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_project_management"/>
</record>

<record id="project_project_lead_rule1" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Project: Lead to view only others document</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_project"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('project_user_access.group_project_lead'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id','!=',user.id)]</field>
</record>
<record id="project_project_lead_rule2" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Project: Lead to write own document</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_project"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('project_user_access.group_project_lead'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
</record>
```

In CSV(Tried with CSV and also Without CSV)

```
access_project_project_group_lead,project_project_group_lead,project.model_project_project,project_user_access.group_project_lead,1,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using two different groups for each record rule and assign users accordingly

```
<record id="group_project_lead_others" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Lead can view others</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_project_management"/>
</record>

  <record id="group_project_lead_own" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Lead can edit own</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_project_management"/>
    </record>

<record id="project_project_lead_rule1" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Project: Lead to view only others document</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_project"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('project_user_access.group_project_lead_others'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id','!=',user.id)]</field>
</record>
<record id="project_project_lead_rule2" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Project: Lead to write own document</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_project"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('project_user_access.group_project_lead_own'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
</record>
```

Comment: i can't get the result. and also we need only one group to map all managers.

Answer (score 0):

Because they have read access on every record use this :

```
<record id="project_project_lead_rule1" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Project: Lead to view only others document</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_project"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('project_user_access.group_project_lead'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[(1,'=', 1)]</field>
</record>
```

When you do this `[('user_id','!=',user.id)]` you are saying that this group is allwode to read only
project of other users not there owns, instead you could do this `['|', ('user_id','!=',user.id), ('user_id','=',user.id)]` but
the convention is to use this `[(1,'=', 1)]` when there is no condition to prevent them from reading any record.

Now because They are allowed to modify there own projects only:

```
<record id="project_project_lead_rule2" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Project: Lead to write own document</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_project"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('project_user_access.group_project_lead'))]"/>
    <!-- apply this domain only in [write, create, unlink] permissions don't forget they are allowed to see other project-->
    <field name="perm_read" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
</record>
```

In you access write file you give them all permission so make sure that they are only allowed to touch there projects `(write, create, delete)`.

Comment: I have tried your technique still rules did not affect. can you give me any reference.

Comment: Did you use noupdate ?  And what is wrong in your access rights now ?  Does the group see other records ?  Or only there own projects

Comment: no i don't use no update. and also i have editted in technical settings. if i use the csv all document had full access if i remove csv all document had edit only mode to all managers.